# Doctrine 2 add new field that auto generates sequence values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a table (class A) that inherits from another table (class B), so obviously table A's primary key references table B's primary key. However, what I'm trying to do is add a new field to table A that should auto increment and also start a specific value, ex. 1000001.

I have tried multiple ways off adding this new field (column) in class A, but I can't get it to work:

```
Class A extends B {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="Identity")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="beer_id", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1000001)
 **/
private $beerIdNumber;
```

How can I make this new column auto generate sequence values, and possibly make it into an additional primary key column or be unique value? (my database is MySql)

Comment: what happens when you use what you have? errors, just doesnt set or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Doctrine 2 Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/basic-mapping.html#sequence-generator):

> The Sequence Generator can currently be used in conjunction with
>   Oracle or Postgres and allows some additional configuration options
>   besides specifying the sequence’s name

It would seem that for you all you need to use is use:

```
Class A extends B {

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="Identity")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
 private $beerIdNumber;
```

Also From the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-generatedvalue):

> @GeneratedValue Specifies which strategy is used for identifier
>   generation for an instance variable which is annotated by @Id. This
>   annotation is optional and only has meaning when used in conjunction
>   with @Id.
>
> If this annotation is not specified with @Id the NONE strategy is used
>   as default.

**HOWEVER**

[Composite Keys](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/basic-mapping.html#composite-keys)

> Doctrine 2 allows to use composite primary keys. There are however
>   some restrictions opposed to using a single identifier. The use of the
>   @GeneratedValue annotation is only supported for simple (not
>   composite) primary keys, which means you can only use composite keys
>   if you generate the primary key values yourself before calling
>   EntityManager#persist() on the entity.
>
> To designate a composite primary key / identifier, simply put the @Id
>   marker annotation on all fields that make up the primary key.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. If add the annotation @ORM\Id to that variable, I get this error when trying to create the schema: `[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException] Entity 'EntityBundle\Entity\A' has a composite identifier but uses an ID generator other than manually assigning (Identity, Sequence). This is not supported.` And it's probably because it already knows that its primary key is the id from its parent.