# Doctrine Entity with 2 Sequence / Identity generated fields

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

**Question:** How do I get Doctrine to allow me to have 2 'SEQUENCE / IDENTITY fields in my Entity?

**Here is my Entity**

```
<?php

namespace CampaignTool\CampaignToolBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Usage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="campaign_data.usage", indexes=    {@ORM\Index(name="usage_fk_usage_category1_idx", columns={"category_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CampaignTool\CampaignToolBundle\Entity\UsageRepository")
 */
class Usage
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="campaign_data.usage_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="act", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
 */
private $act;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Get act
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAct()
{
    return $this->act;
}

}
```

**My Problem is:**

When I remove the following line from **private $act**, I can **CREATE** the Entity with an 'act' generated by the database. However I cannot see that 'act' when I try to **EDIT** the Entity.

`@ORM\Column(name="act", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)`

If I add the above line, then I can see that 'act' when I try to **EDIT** the Entity. However then I get the following Error when I try **CREATE**

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO campaign_data.usage (id, quality, comment, category_id, act, name, active, cost_group) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [42, null, null, 22, null, "Example__Usage__#17", 0, null]:

SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "act" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (42, null, null, null, Example__Usage__#17, 22, null, 2015-05-21 11:01:46.01213, 2015-05-21 11:01:46.081427, f).
```

What I need is to have the field treated just like 'id'. Read-only! I thought removing the setter would do this, but no luck, it still wants to insert the field as null into the database.

Comment: So you're trying to have a composite key where both keys are a `GeneratedValue`? [I don't think that's possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22345822/2043204)

Comment: Its not a composite key. One field is the Primary key generated by a Sequence in the Database. The other field is just 'generated by a Sequence in the database'.

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution:**
set the second SEQUENCE manually at 'persistence' time in the controller.
I'm not entirely happy with this since I feel it is a solution 'outside' the framework. Wanted to avoid this.
**BTW:** I do not post a value for the act from the Create Form.

**My Entity:**

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="act", type="string", length=45)
 *
 */
private $act;

/**
 * Set act
 *
 * @param string $act
 * @return usage
 */
public function setAct($act)
{
    $this->act = $act;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get act
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAct()
{
    return $this->act;
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = new Usage();

    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity, $em);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $data = $form->getData();

        // This is needed for setting the act SEQUENCE value before we flush()
        $newUsage = new Usage();
        $newUsage->setQuality($data->getQuality());
        $newUsage->setComment($data->getComment());
        $newUsage->setCategoryId($data->getCategoryId());
        $newUsage->setAct($this->getActSequence($em));
        $newUsage->setName($data->getName());
        $newUsage->setTelephoneNumbers($data->getTelephoneNumbers());
        $newUsage->setCostGroup($data->getCostGroup());
        $newUsage->setCampaignAliases($data->getCampaignAliases());
        $newUsage->setActive($data->getActive());



        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($newUsage);

        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('campaign_tool_usage_show', array('id' => $newUsage->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

 public function getActSequence($entityManager)
{
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addScalarResult('act','act');
    $query = $entityManager->createNativeQuery("select mydb.function_generate_act() as act;", $rsm);

    $act = $query->getResult();
    return($act[0]['act']);
}
```