# Adding a primary key to existing entity that has a unique constraint on two fields in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an existing Symfony entity:

```
/**
 * MyApp\AppBundle\Entity\UserSelection
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_selection",uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique", columns={"user_id", "selection_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\AppBundle\Entity\UserSelectionRepository")
 */
class UserSelection
{

    /**
     * @var integer $userId
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
     * @var integer $selectionId
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="selection_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $selectionId;
}
```

I'm trying to refactor some code and when running

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:form MyAppAppBundle:UserSelection
```

I get

> The form generator does not support entity classes with multiple primary keys.

...which is understandable ([thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345822)). Is it fine to use the entity as is and manually create the form type? Or is it better to put in an id field in the entity? If I do that, what specific configuration is best?

For example

```
/**
 * MyApp\AppBundle\Entity\UserSelection
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_selection",uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique", columns={"user_id", "selection_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\AppBundle\Entity\UserSelectionRepository")
 */
class UserSelection
{

     /**
     * @var integer $id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer $userId
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
    * @var integer $selectionId
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(name="selection_id", type="integer")
    */
    private $selectionId;
}
```

produces an error

> has a composite identifier but uses an ID generator other than manually assigning (Identity, Sequence). This is not supported.

Then if I do

```
/**
 * MyApp\AppBundle\Entity\UserSelection
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_selection",uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique", columns={"user_id", "selection_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\AppBundle\Entity\UserSelectionRepository")
 */
class UserSelection
{

     /**
     * @var integer $id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer $userId
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
    * @var integer $selectionId
    * @ORM\Column(name="selection_id", type="integer")
    */
    private $selectionId;
}
```

When I run the resulting dump-sql

```
ALTER TABLE user_selection ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

I get

> Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

So, in terms of best practices, what is the way to proceed?

**Update**

So I can make this work, but it requires two steps. First, create an $id column

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;
```

Run `ALTER TABLE user_selection ADD id INT NOT NULL;`

Then, in this order,

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $id;
```

Which produces `ALTER TABLE user_selection CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);`

Is there a way to combine this so that all that is needed after changes to the entity is a single dump-sql command?

Comment: What if you use an auto-increment id instead of an UUID one in the 2d solution? It seems the ALTER doesn't work because it doesn't know which UUID affect to the exisiting records. (You could also try to add a simple "id" column, populate it with UUID, then ALTER the table to use it as primary key)

Comment: @Veve I tried that and got "there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key". However, it does seem to populate correctly, some of the time I am trying various configurations... I'll try to replicate it

Comment: @Veve Yes I can make it work, but it requires two steps

Comment: What's the problem with 2 steps?

Comment: @Veve I'm trying to make it fit into one pull request in version control. I mean two is possible, but it feels kind of clunky.

Comment: It's not a little change, I really don't see the problem with these 2 modifications, which can be in one pull request by the way, no need for 2 PR for 2 changes.

Answer (score 1):

`UUID` By default is not an integer value, so your entity should look like this

```
/**
 * MyApp\AppBundle\Entity\UserSelection
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_selection",uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique", columns={"user_id", "selection_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\AppBundle\Entity\UserSelectionRepository")
 */
class UserSelection
{

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer $userId
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
    * @var integer $selectionId
    * @ORM\Column(name="selection_id", type="integer")
    */
    private $selectionId;
}
```

Comment: So the SQL is  `ALTER TABLE user_selection ADD id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:guid)', ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)` and I get `"Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'"`

Comment: Try  change `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")` to `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")`

Comment: Then I get `there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

Comment: It's because in MySQL table you have `id` column with `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: Try change `MySQL` engine to `MyISAM`.